# jQuery .click() event for CSS pseudoelement (:before/:after)?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, click, pseudo-element

I want to trigger a jQuery animation when content that I am inserting through the CSS pseudoelements `:before:` and `:after` is clicked. However, I'm not sure how to do this; my first guess, `$(#id:before).click()` didn't work. Is this part of jQuery's functionality? If so, how would I select the `before`/`after` content?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/before /after

Comment: @Mike Soule: That is not the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery does not support the CSS `:before` and `:after` selectors. <strike>To select siblings, use `.siblings()` and then filter from there.</strike>

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: +1 for the mere lack of support. I should say, though, `.siblings()` does not select pseudo-elements, it selects entirely different elements from the currently-scoped ones. The `:before` and `:after` content elements aren't siblings themselves anyway, they are children of the specified elements (but siblings of its content). More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

Comment: Thanks for this, and thanks @BoltClock for the clarification. I'll give jQuery .before/.after methods a shot.