# CSS li with close button

Tags: css

**Problem:**
I need list with close option, the code which i tried sofar is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/7evx02zf/1/)**.

**For ex:**  Suppose I clicked on close button of Test Content1, it should be removed from the list.

It might be simple, but I'm working in this for a long time to find solution with no luck

```
<ul class="list_sbar"> 
    <li> <a href="#">Test content1</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Test content</a>  </li>
</ul>
```

With the code I showed, I can be able to link whole `list` block as single link, not able to give separate functionality for close

**Note:**
As you can see in my demo the whole block(not only for text) is considered as single link, where I need different link/tag for close, that's why I mentioned I'm not able to give separate link for close.

Even I'm ready to accept separate class for close, no need for close functionality(JS), I just want different behavior/link for close from `li a`

I don't want to **close the list if its clicked, until I clicked on close button** **it should not get closed**

Comment: You want to use jQuery? Where's your code?

Comment: css - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/asj23fox/

Comment: See my answer, check the mouse position before remove an element.

Comment: @HorsSujet : Thanks for your effort but i updated my question bit clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have javascript event on `::before` or `::after`.

But you can check the x position of the mouse, like this :

```
$(".list_sbar li").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() - 34 <= e.offsetX)
        $(this).remove();
});
```

See js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pf9j7ry4/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do it with events like this.

Please note that I am using `jQuery` here as I see you didn't include that as a tag in your question.

```
$(".list_sbar a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });   
});
```

I updated your example to show this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7evx02zf/4/)**.

**EDIT**: [jQuery does not support adding events on pseudoelements (:before, :after)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542392/jquery-click-event-for-css-pseudoelement-before-after)

So what you need to do is redesign your close buttons, make them as actual elements.

Comment: yes i need this close functionality but if i click on any place of the list it gets closed, i need anchor should point to some link and close functionality to be different

Comment: Do you want it hidden or completely removed?

Comment: i want to remove but only if i click on close

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/7evx02zf/3/).

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Comment: I don't want to close the list if its clicked until I clicked on close button, it should not close

Answer (score 0):

Do this You Will Get Your Desire Result

```
 $(".list_sbar").on('click','li',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();

});
```

Demo is Here **http://jsfiddle.net/7evx02zf/5/**

Answer (score 0):

variant on css

use pseudo-class `:checked` with `input` elements of type radio and checkbox.

```css
ul.list_sbar {    
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.list_sbar li{
    position:relative;
}
ul.list_sbar li > div{
    clear:both;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
    min-height:22px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 9px;
}
ul.list_sbar li:first-child {
    border-top: solid 1px #ddd;
}
ul.list_sbar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 33;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    float:left;
}
ul.list_sbar li > div:hover {
    color: #111;
    background: #FFF2BE;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #333;
}
ul.list_sbar li input{
    display: none;
}
ul.list_sbar li label:hover{
    color: #f00;
}
ul.list_sbar li label{
    position: absolute; top: 50%;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 8px;    
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    color: #999;
    font-family:  calibri, sans-serif; 
    cursor: pointer;    
    transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
ul.list_sbar li input:checked + label + div{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list_sbar"> 
    <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r1" name="r1" /><label for="r1">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content1</a></div>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r2" name="r2" /><label for="r2">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content2</a></div>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r3" name="r3" /><label for="r3">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content3</a></div>
    </li>
   <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r4" name="r4" /><label for="r4">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content4</a></div>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r5" name="r5" /><label for="r5">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content4</a></div>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r6" name="r6" /><label for="r6">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content5</a></div>
    </li>
     <li> 
        <input type="radio" id="r7" name="r7" /><label for="r7">x</label>
        <div><a href="#">Test content6</a></div>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

I hope this helps